# CRM 2011: How to override error window - possibilities

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I would like to override some behavior during error handing in CRM (error windows specifically). Is it possible? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Is it possible to call events before and after - js, workflow, plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You can always handle errors for the code that you write and it is good practice to do this since users usually don't know what to do with the native error handlers or what they mean.  Add your own try/catch blocks to the code and then writing those errors to a log file, a log entity, e-mail support, etc.  Even with JS you can add your own try catch blocks and handle them however you want.

If you were looking to modify the error handling for native MSCRM errors would require you to open up the source code and modify the  JS/HTML files, etc.  Doing this can cause issues with Upgrades, hot fixes, dealing with MS support, and a whole host of other reasons why this is a bad idea.

Comment: The first part is a good advice. I am already using logging mechanism. The second part is also a good information, but I would like to know which files I need to change to modify the behavior (at least look and feel of an error window).